# Controlling speed of frames for animated gif

Tags: animation

How can I control the speed of the animation? I would like the frames to pass one value per second, in others words, one frame per second. Is there any function that controls this output?

```
g = Graphics[Table[{ Text[ Style[#, FontSize -> 40, Bold, Red], {0, 0}]}, 1]] & /@ Range[10]   
  Export["C:\\Users\\JohnPeter\\Desktop\\Count.gif", g]
```

[image]

Comment: `Export["count.gif", g, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]`

Comment: Use the option `"DisplayDurations"` of `Export`.See this `ref/format/GIF->Elements`

Comment: @yode - but that documentation is confusing since it only says that those are advance `Import` elements, not saying anything about `Export`

Comment: @JasonB Yes,some other string options confuse me as well.Hard to find in its documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [JasonB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128101/controlling-speed-of-frames-for-animated-gif/128103#comment346496_128101) comment

One frame in $0,5sec$:

```
g = Graphics[ Table[{Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 40, Bold, Red], {0, 0}]}, 1]] & /@ Range[10] Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Documents\\Wolfram Mathematica\\1 - \ NB\\anima.gif", g, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

[image]

One frame in $1sec$:

```
g = Graphics[ Table[{Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 40, Bold, Red], {0, 0}]}, 1]] & /@ Range[10] Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Documents\\Wolfram Mathematica\\1 - \ NB\\anima.gif", g, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

[image]