# How to export an animation as a video with the same animation rate as the animation itself?

Tags: export

I made a simulation of a pendulum oscillating and then tried to export it as a .avi file. The animation is smooth and lasts for 2 minutes as intended. The .avi file however is way quickier. How can I have the video running at the same speed as the animation inside the notebook?

I named the Animate p and export it like this

```
Export["p.avi", p]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Look this:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128101/controlling-speed-of-frames-for-animated-gif

Comment: Look for the term `DisplayDurations`